# Is the first execution of a function always slower than the second?

Tags: javascript

I just noticed that if I have the exact same function and measure it's performance, then the first execution is always slower than the second one.

I tried it several times and the result is always the same.

```
const myF = () => console.log("hello");

console.time("1");
myF();
console.timeEnd("1");

console.time("2");
myF();
console.timeEnd("2");
```

First I thought the result of the first execution is somehow cached and therefore in the second execution it is faster. But I also tried with different functions that are only slightly different. But again, the result are the same as before: The function executed first is faster than the second one.

```
const myF = () => console.log("hello");
const myF2 = () => console.log("world");

console.time("1");
myF(); // 1 is slower than 2
console.timeEnd("1");

console.time("2");
myF2();
console.timeEnd("2");
```

Here I executed the 2nd function first

```
const myF = () => console.log("hello");
const myF2 = () => console.log("world");

console.time("2");
myF2(); // 2 is slower than 1
console.timeEnd("2");

console.time("1");
myF();
console.timeEnd("1");
```

Is the way I use the `console.time` resp. `console.timeEnd` correct? If so, why would the first execution be slower than the second execution? It's probably something stupid that I missed. I can't imagine the performance of the exact same function to be dependent on which line it is executed....

**Tested on Chrome 78.0; Linux 19.04**

Answer (score 0):

Its because of when your function executes first time, compiler interprets that function to machine code(assembly instruction for function) and stores this CPU instruction in memory. When you execute same function second time compilers directly executes interpreted machine code that's why second time function executes faster.

Comment: Why would executing two (slightly) *different* functions show the same effect?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Your anonymous functions are different, but the `console.log` is the same (with different parameters) perhaps that's the bit that's pre-compiled the second time around.

Comment: You are probably right. Is there a way to verify that?